# KTDrumTrigger with 64-bit Cubase 5.5.3

Tags: midi, vst, cubase

I google'd around to find a way to replace a poor sounding snare track with samples, and fell upon KTDrumTrigger VST plugin. The behavior of this plugin is exactly what I am looking for:

- turn audio "hits" into midi notes, to be output into a midi channel (Battery 3, for example).

I can confirm that MIDI works on my setup (I use a MIDI keyboard all the time for drums and keyboard sounds, etc.).

I see lots of reports online that MIDI bus on Cubase 5 64-bit just does not support this kind of behavior, but 32-bit does. Is there a way to work this? Anyone have any success?

**UPDATE**

Here's a [link](http://www.cubase.net/phpbb2/viewtopic.php?p=975119&sid=19169d77282bc8b357852e000685591c) to one of the articles.

Comment: I am not really as familiar with cubase as I used to be anymore. Could you please link to some of these reports?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't really explain why 64-bit MIDI input and output doesn't work simultaneously in Cubase 5.5.3.

What I **CAN** confirm is that installing 32-bit Cubase 5 and then running all the updates to 5.5.3 on a 64-bit Windows 7 Ultimate machine allows KTDrumTrigger to work just as advertised.

As an aside, I can't believe how much more stable the 32-bit version is over 64-bit. The only downside is 32-bit takes a bit longer for processing (i.e. initial program cold start, VST track processing such as normalize or compression, etc.), which I will trade any day for the stability I've experienced since uninstalling 64-bit. I used to expect crashes every time I fired up Cubase, but with 32-bit installation I haven't had a single one. I don't know what Steinberg is doing, but I hope they fixed that in Cubase 6, that's pretty poor development practices to introduce such a large gap in behavior across environments.